# I want to create a super admin or system admin from backend or cli in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, oauth

I am building a application where registration page is only available to admin user so I can give registration page to admin user. But I need to create an admin user which can create those users. I can not do it by any Api.

**Problem**

I am using JWT Token based Authention. In JWT Token based Authention it needed certain procedure to create user by C# code.
Is there any way I can create user from backhand without API call?

```
        [HttpPost]  
        [Route("register")]  
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)  
        {  
            var userExists = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);  
            if (userExists != null)  
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User already exists!" });  
  
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()  
            {  
                Email = model.Email,  
                SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),  
                UserName = model.Username  
            };  
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);  
            if (!result.Succeeded)  
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User creation failed! Please check user details and try again." });  
  
            return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "User created successfully!" });  
        }  
  
        [HttpPost]  
        [Route("register-admin")]  
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAdmin(RegisterModel model)  
        {  
            var userExists = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);  
            if (userExists != null)  
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User already exists!" });  
  
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()  
            {  
                Email = model.Email,  
                SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),  
                UserName = model.Username  
            };  
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);  
            if (!result.Succeeded)  
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User creation failed! Please check user details and try again." });  
  
            if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Admin))  
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(UserRoles.Admin));  
            if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.User))  
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(UserRoles.User));  
  
            if (await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Admin))  
            {  
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.Admin);  
            }  
  
            return Ok(new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "User created successfully!" });  
        } 


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            // Allow Cross for Centain Network

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                builder =>
                                {
                                    builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"]);
                                });
            });


            services.AddControllers();

            // For Entity Framework  
            services.AddDbContext<DentalDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));  
  
            // For Identity  
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => 
            {
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            })  
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DentalDbContext>()  
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();  


              
            // Adding Authentication  
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>  
            {  
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  
            })  
  
            // Adding Jwt Bearer  
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>  
            {  
                options.SaveToken = true;  
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;  
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()  
                {  
                    ValidateIssuer = true,  
                    ValidateAudience = true,  
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],  
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],  
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))  
                };  
            });  

        }
```

Comment: OAuth 2 is built on top of Open ID.What you mean by Auth2? Do you use microsoft Identity?

Comment: Whether you are using Asp.net Core Identity in your application? If you are using Asp.net Core Identity to manage users and roles, since the password was hashed, when you insert new users into the database, you have to hashed the password. And if you have enabled the email confirm, you still enable the email confirm when insert a new user. If you are not using asp.net core identity, after login using Oauth2, you could connect the database and insert a new super admin user, or directly access the database via SSMS and insert a new item in the Users Table.

Comment: @SlobodanT  It is JWT token based authentication . Though I am trying to create hashed password from MSSQL . I have updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, If you use Identity of Microsoft. There is way out for this.
In Program.cs

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            try
            {
                using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();

                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                if (!context.Users.Any())
                {
                    var superAdminUser= new IdentityUser
                    {
                        UserName = "SuperAdmin"
                    };

                    userManager.CreateAsync(superAdminUser, "SuperAdminPassword").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                    //Roles contains user, user contains claims
                    var adminClaim = new Claim("Role", "SuperAdminUser");

                    userManager.AddClaimAsync(SuperAdminUser, adminClaim).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            host.Run();
        }
```

In Startup use authorization.

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
 {
     options.AddPolicy("SuperAdmin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Role", "SuperAdmin"));
 });
```

Add Authorize in Controller Specially for SuperAdmin Role

```
[Authorize(Policy = "SuperAdmin ")]
 public class SecretController : Controller
 {}
```

Comment: userManager.AddClaimAsync(SuperAdminUser, adminClaim).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); Is it superAdminUser instand of  SuperAdminUser

Comment: `superAdminUser` is the instance of Super Admin User. `userManager.AddClaimAsync(SuperAdminUser, adminClaim).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` Adds super admin role to super admin user.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your Auth DBContext then run the migration command

```
 var user = new IdentityUser { 
        UserName = " "
       };

      //set user password
      PasswordHasher<AppUser> ph = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
      user.passwordHash = ph.HashPassword(user, "the password");

      //seed user
      builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasData(user);
        
      //set user role to admin
      builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(new 
       IdentityUserRole<string> { 
       RoleId = "your role ID", 
       UserId = "The User ID" 
      });
```